# See more than one message on lock screen

Tags: 8.0, lock-screen, messaging

On Windows Phone 8, you can customize the lock screen, but only messages OR facebook OR whatsapp messages can be shown (the only show the number of notifications). And only one message is shown.

Is there a way of showing more messages? The screen real state is really large here.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of receiving more than one message is to find an app the shows multiple items. Although technically, you'd still only be displaying one item, but one things that shows many.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good app out there that allows you to add tiles to the lock screen. This would be the best way (from what I have seen) to allow to you make better use of the real estate on the lock screen.

[The app is called Lockmix](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/lockmix/f010a687-6818-4cd2-876f-710e9a83f324).

Comment: No option to add text messages or whatsapp, only facebook (but apparently any notification, not only facebook messages as i wanted)